# Appending ListView from onScrollListener

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am trying to update my listview to make an "endless scroll". What happens is that the first 40 results load fine, when i get to the bottom of the scroll, next 40 results replace the first 40...

What I want is for second set of 40 results to add to the first 40 so I have an endless list and ability to scroll back to the beginning of the list.

I am posting my code below. Thank you!

```
public class SearchResults extends Activity implements BannerAdListener, OnScrollListener{

    private LinearLayout bottomNav;
    private ListView ringtoneList;
    private int start = 0, num = 40, curPage = 1;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private ArrayList<Ringtone> ringtones;
    private MoPubView moPubView;  
    private String searchString;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            // no search string defined
            finish();
        } else {
            searchString = extras.getString("search_string");
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.search_results);    

        ringtoneList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ringtone_list);
        ringtoneList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SearchResults.this, RingtoneView.class);
                i.putExtra("ringtone", ringtones.get(position));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        performSearch();

        moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
        moPubView.setAdUnitId(Utils.MoPubBannerId);
        moPubView.loadAd();
        moPubView.setBannerAdListener(this);

        ringtoneList.setOnScrollListener(this);

    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, final int visibleCount, int totalCount) {

            Log.i("List", "firstVisible="+firstVisible+" visibleCount="+visibleCount+" totalCount="+totalCount);

            boolean loadMore = firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

            if(loadMore) {

                Log.i("List", "Loading More Results");                

                curPage++;
                start = num * (curPage-1);

                new Thread() {

                    public void run() {

                        ringtones = Utils.search(start, num, searchString);

                        if (ringtones != null && ringtones.size() > 0) {

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    ringtoneList.setAdapter(new RingtoneRowAdapter(SearchResults.this, ringtones));
                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchResults.this)
                                    .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.context_info)).setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.context_noresult))
                                    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.context_ok), null).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }
                }

                .start();
         }
    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int s) { } 

    private void performSearch() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SearchResults.this, getResources().getString(R.string.loading_message), getResources().getString(R.string.loading_search), true); 
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                ringtones = Utils.search(start, num, searchString);
                if (ringtones != null && ringtones.size() > 0) {
                    updateList();
                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchResults.this)
                            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.context_info)).setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.context_noresult))
                            .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.context_ok), null).show();
                            ringtoneList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            bottomNav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void updateList() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Log.d("search", "ringtones.size() " + ringtones.size());
                ringtoneList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ringtoneList.setAdapter(new RingtoneRowAdapter(SearchResults.this, ringtones));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't be 100% sure, I think your problem has to do with the fact that you're setting a new adapter that only has the section of ringtones that in loads.  It probably has to do with this snippet:

```
ringtones = Utils.search(start, num, searchString);

if (ringtones != null && ringtones.size() > 0) {

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ringtoneList.setAdapter(new RingtoneRowAdapter(SearchResults.this, ringtones));
        }
    });

}
```

Instead of putting an entirely new array of ringtones, you should add on to the one you already have.  Your `ringtones` variable is already an instance variable, so I'm sure if you changed this line:

```
ringtones = Utils.search(start, num, searchString);
```

to the following:

```
ringtones.addAll(Utils.search(start, num, searchString));
```

It might fix your problem.

Comment: I was hoping it would work as that is the simplest solution, however, it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException error on adAll line.

Comment: In your `onCreate()`, try putting the line `ringtones = new ArrayList<Ringtone>()`.  The issue from what I can tell is that you're not instantiating it.  I would put it just after calling `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit messy, but your updateList method is creating a NEW RingtoneRowAdapter. You should ADD items to the list and call

```
mRingtoneRowAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

That will tell the adapter to get new views (if needed) along with a lot of internal stuff happening at Adapter's level. So it's kinda:

```
   private void updateList() {
         handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if ( mAdapter == null ) { 
                   mAdapter = new RingtoneRowAdapter(SearchResults.this, ringtones);
                   ringtoneList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                } else {
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                ringtoneList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

And of course, as already suggested, don't init your ringtones array all the time. Just add data to it.

You don't need (most of the times) to hide the list, you can add in your layout, any View (including a full Layout!) with an id of:

```
android:id="@android:id/empty"
```

And if your ListView has an id of android:id="@id/android:list", and you're in a ListFragment or ListActivity, then when the list is empty, the "empty" layout will be shown (which can be a dummy view if you don't want to see it).

Just suggestions :)

**UPDATE**: For your null, I see that the logic is a little bit weird and since we don't know the requirements for your app (i.e. what to do if there are no results, what to do if the results are invalid, etc.) I'll assume you just want to make sure it works and deal with that later.

So with that in mind, I see two problems.

1. I assume your Utils.search method can return null, because you're checking for it. To me that feels strange, I'd rather return an empty array indicating that the search produced no results; that little remark aside, you are not checking (or we don't know because we haven't seen the source for your search method), if the searchString is null or not.
2. You haven't provided a stack trace, so we can't tell where the null is happening (either inside search or ?)

A quick solution would be to check for null before searching… I would personally do this INSIDE the search function.

Something like:

```
public ArrayList<Ringtone> search(final int start, final int num, final String searchString) {

   if ( searchString == null ) {
       //DECIDE WHAT YOU WANT TO DO, EITHER:
       return null;
       // OR YOU CAN RETURN AN EMPTY ARRAY
       return new ArrayList<Ringtone>(); 
    }
   // You should check for these (change according to your rules)
   if (start < 0 ) {
      start = 0; // protect yourself from bad data.
   }
   if ( num < 0 ) {
       num = 0; 
   } 
    /// THE REST OF YOUR search FUNCTION

   return <your array>
}
```

Now another thing is that you may want the search to return incremental results (so you can ADD them to your array (instead of returning a new array every time). For that, as already suggested, use the addAll trick, but then, DON'T return null, return an new empty array, so there's no harm done if there's nothing else to add.

Comment: I tried this method and it seems to work but now ringtones.addAll(Utils.search(start, num, searchString)); returns me a NullPointerException ... any ideas?

Comment: One of these is null at some point: the ringtones array, your Utils seems to be a Singleton so I guess it's ok. start, num or the searchString are null/invalid. Add a breakpoint and check for null values, this is Java so everything can be null! :) My guess is searchString. You're doing searchString = extras.getString("search_string"); but if search_string is not there… your string will be null.

Comment: thank you. i used you updateList() method with Andrew's help on instantiating the array.